# Add a newline after three numbers in a list

Tags: python

I want to add a new line after three things that I append to my list.

For example, in my code I'm going `for` a loop from 1 to 100 and every loop I add `i` to a list, My problem is that I have no clue how to do that every loop it will add a new line to my `result` list , so the output will be:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
.....
```

**Current Output:**

It just add me all the numbers without a new line.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9......
```

**Code:**

```
first = []
second = []
third = []
result = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    first.append(i)
    second.append(i)
    third.append(i)
    result.append(third + second + third)
    result.append('\n')

print(result)
```

Comment: so, your end goal is to create a list of numbers 1-100, with a '\n' entry in between every 3 entries? (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, "\n", 4, 5, 6, "\n", ...]`)

Comment: @AustinPhilp Yes.

Comment: FYI, adding an element `'\n'` is not adding a new line anywhere.

Comment: @רועי לוי Welcome to Stack Overflow, Actually I agree with **Jab**, I think there is no list structure (as variable) with new line in it , all answers either a list with '\n' as element or string or just print formatting. you said _I want to save the new list into a variable, so I can use it later_ . if you want to separate each 3 elements, you can use **list of lists**.

Comment: You mix formatting print statements and storing data. There is now way to store a 'new line' in a list, at best you can do is to store a '\n' new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your goal is to generate a list that literally contains `"\n"` as every third element, you can accomplish this using the [modulus operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html) to add a `"\n"` every 3 entries.

```
result = []
for i in range(1, 101):
  result.append(i)
  if len(result) % 3 == 0:
    result.append("\n")
```

EDIT:

For clarity, in order to print the `result` list, use the following line

```
print(''.join(str(x) for x in result))
```

which will produce the output

```
123
456
789
...
```

Comment: Its not working, it is just adding the word '\n' but not really down a line.

Comment: Are you just entering `>>> result` to view the result? or `print(''.join(result))`? if you just type `>>> result` the python interpreter will return the **representation** of the string, not the escaped string itself. Print will resolve escape characters such as `\n`

Comment: I want to save the new list into a variable, so I can use it later. And it will add a new line every time I use it.

Comment: Also, your program is not working, error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Thank you, but I still not getting what I want, now, the output is :**123 456 789 101112** I want to add a new line every 3 numbers.

Comment: I accepted this answer, this is the best answer from here. I fixed the output by changing to `if len(result) % 3 == 0: result.append('\n')` and not `if i % 3 == 0:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Let me know if you need more details.

```
for i in range(30):

    print('%3d, ' %i, end='')

    if (i+1) % 3 == 0:
        print()
```

Output:

```
  0,   1,   2, 
  3,   4,   5, 
  6,   7,   8, 
  9,  10,  11, 
 12,  13,  14, 
 15,  16,  17, 
 18,  19,  20, 
 21,  22,  23, 
 24,  25,  26, 
 27,  28,  29,
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to this with lists, like my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ""
for i in range(1,101):
  result += f"{i}" + (", " if i % 3 else "\n")

print(result)
```

achieves it with a minimum of fuss. When the index has no remainder when divided by 3 it will start a new line in the string. Though it maybe nicer to tab separate the output once numbers get bigger.

```
result = ""
for i in range(1,101):
  result += f"{i}" + (",\t" if i % 3 else "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do this with lists.

Comment: Why? If you want to display the list you just do this. If you don't want to display the list, then what's the point of adding the newline character?

Comment: Because I need that, its important to me, I have no clue how to do that. also, In my complete code I not only print the list.

Comment: look at my solution, it prints lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output with the `%` operator and the `sep` argument in `print` like this:

```py
same_line = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    same_line.append(i)
    if not i % 3 or i == 100:
        print(*(value for value in same_line), sep=', ')
        same_line = []

>>> 
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15
16, 17, 18
19, 20, 21
22, 23, 24
25, 26, 27
28, 29, 30
31, 32, 33
34, 35, 36
37, 38, 39
40, 41, 42
43, 44, 45
46, 47, 48
49, 50, 51
52, 53, 54
55, 56, 57
58, 59, 60
61, 62, 63
64, 65, 66
67, 68, 69
70, 71, 72
73, 74, 75
76, 77, 78
79, 80, 81
82, 83, 84
85, 86, 87
88, 89, 90
91, 92, 93
94, 95, 96
97, 98, 99
100
```

Comment: But I want to add '\n' to the list it self

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
temp = []
for i in range(100):
    temp.append(i)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(temp)
        temp = []
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
...
[97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: I want to add a new line to my list.

Comment: every line should be a new list? Or all the 99 numbers should be in one list? Because in my solution you have 33 lists now, each containing 3 elements. How do you want to add a new line? I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without loops using zip and some tricky list manipulation:

```
list(sum(zip(*[iter(range(1, 101))]*3, ['\n']*100), tuple()))
```

---

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, '\n', 4, 5, 6, '\n', 7, 8, 9, '\n', 10, 11, 12, '\n', 13, 14, 15, '\n',16, 17, 18, '\n', 19, 20, 21, '\n', 22, 23, 24, '\n', 25, 26, 27, '\n', 28, 29, 30, '\n', 31, 32, 33, '\n', 34, 35, 36, '\n', 37, 38, 39, '\n', 40, 41, 42, '\n', 43, 44, 45, '\n', 46, 47, 48, '\n', 49, 50, 51, '\n', 52, 53, 54, '\n', 55, 56, 57, '\n', 58, 59, 60, '\n', 61, 62, 63, '\n', 64, 65, 66, '\n', 67, 68, 69, '\n', 70, 71, 72, '\n', 73, 74, 75, '\n', 76, 77, 78, '\n', 79, 80, 81, '\n', 82, 83, 84, '\n', 85, 86, 87, '\n', 88, 89, 90, '\n', 91, 92, 93, '\n', 94, 95, 96, '\n', 97, 98, 99, '\n']
```

If you want it printed as your original example use something like this:

```
print(*map(', '.join, zip(*[iter(map(str, range(1, 101)))]*3)), sep='\n')
```

---

Output:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15
16, 17, 18
19, 20, 21
22, 23, 24
25, 26, 27
28, 29, 30
31, 32, 33
34, 35, 36
37, 38, 39
40, 41, 42
43, 44, 45
46, 47, 48
49, 50, 51
52, 53, 54
55, 56, 57
58, 59, 60
61, 62, 63
64, 65, 66
67, 68, 69
70, 71, 72
73, 74, 75
76, 77, 78
79, 80, 81
82, 83, 84
85, 86, 87
88, 89, 90
91, 92, 93
94, 95, 96
97, 98, 99
```

Comment: Hey, I want to add a new line to the list and also make it really down a line in the list.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean... A list isn't a print formatting it's a way to store data.

Comment: Yes, but it must be a way to add a new line in a list, look in the answers here.

Comment: The other answers are showing ways to print data in a list or actual lists. Please be more specific as to your expected output.